# Session IDs in (simple) universal composability

Tags: universal-composability

In the [simple UC framework paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/553), there is a brief discussion on session identifiers (*sid*s) on page 13. It states

> The main protocol is given a session identifier *sid*

but it is not entirely clear to me how this happens. I understand that the (S)UC framework requires the *sid* to be unique and known to all parties.

- Can I just assume that the *sid* is written to the code tapes of all machines (including the router, adversary and environment) **before** execution starts (similar to how all security tapes are initialized)? Or is something more subtle going on?
- Does the "main ideal functionality" (page 8: the functionality that creates local copies of the actual functionality) get initialized with the *sid*?